# PHP want to loop through all the files in folders which folders are in folder

Tags: php

So basically I have folder which contains folders and in these folders i have

some images .jpg and some txt files

So i want to loop through these folders and then loop through all the files inside and append them to div via Javascript

So far i i will try something like this
Just need some PHP advices and basically is this a proper way to do this

```
<?php
    $directory = '/path/to/files';

    if (! is_dir($directory)) {
        exit('Invalid diretory path');
    }    

    foreach (scandir($directory) as $file // $file needs to be replaced with $folder for examle) {
        if ('.' === $file) continue; //what is this doing
        if ('..' === $file) continue; // and what is this doing

         //get path of the current folder via PHP
         // create the div with classes and id via javascript 
         // i know javascript so i skip this part

        foreach (scandir($directory) as $file) {
        if ('.' === $file) continue;
        if ('..' === $file) continue;

        //append img with src='php given path' and some classes
        //append some 'html h3' and some 'html p' and one 'html button'
        }
        //append the div with the html tags to a particular div i want
        // all  explained in '//' i can do via javascript so i need only help with PHP
    }


?>
```

I think in the firs loop i have to remove

```
if ('.' === $file) continue; 
 if ('..' === $file) continue;
```

Answer (score 0):

If the structure is that simple as you describe then have a look at glob

```
if (! is_dir($directory)) {
    exit('Invalid diretory path');
}    

foreach (glob($directory . '/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $folder) {

     echo $folder . PHP_EOL; // this is a debug output. You do not need it

     // full path to folder is in $folder
     //get path of the current folder via PHP
     // create the div with classes and id via javascript 
     // i know javascript so i skip this part

    foreach (glob($folder . '/*.{jpg,txt}',GLOB_BRACE) as $file) {

        echo $file . PHP_EOL; // this is a debug output. You do not need it

        // Full path to image is in $file
        //append img with src='php given path' and some classes
        //append some 'html h3' and some 'html p' and one 'html button'
    }
    //append the div with the html tags to a particular div i want
    // all  explained in '//' i can do via javascript so i need only help with PHP
}
```

Comment: can remake my php code with your script so i really understand what you saying im really new to PHP have done just front end before